# c++ templates - (type deduction compile time error)

Tags: c++, templates

i trying to implement a parsing to a xml reader and i have a function or a set of function that implements the parsing necessary to get de values from de xml files and set the variables, i have implemented a couple of templetized function for generic use, but i am stuck in a compilation error, the compiler is trying to replace all functions that are templetized in the method and generated compile time error (type deduction). I was trying to indicated to the compiler that each branch is a diferent case by expliciting the type, but is not working, here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
namespace
{
  int cantidad_repeticiones;
  int execution_code;
  bool should_report;
  bool time_stamp;
  std::string cmd_description;
  int cmd_id;
  unsigned delay_entre_comandos;

  void alpha_to_bool(bool *aBool,const std::string & aString)
  {
    std::istringstream(aString) >> std::boolalpha >> (*aBool);
  }


  template<typename T>
  void convertoToNumber( T * aNumber, const std::string & aString)
  {
    std::stringstream  mStringstream(aString);
    mStringstream >>  (*aNumber);
  }
  template<typename T>
  void set_option(T * aValuePtr,const char * xml_type,const char * xml_value )
  {
    std::string type(xml_type);
    std::string aValue(xml_value);
    if(type=="float") convertoToNumber(aValuePtr,aValue);
    if(type=="bool") alpha_to_bool(aValuePtr,aValue);
    if(type=="int") convertoToNumber(aValuePtr,aValue);
    if(type=="unsigned") convertoToNumber(aValuePtr,aValue);
    if(type=="double") convertoToNumber(aValuePtr,aValue);
  }
  void parse_xml_option(const char * xml_option,const char * xml_type,const char * xml_value)
  {
    std::string string_cache(xml_option);
    if(string_cache=="timestamp") set_option(&time_stamp,xml_type,xml_value);
    if(string_cache=="repeticiones") set_option(&cantidad_repeticiones,xml_type,xml_value);
    if(string_cache=="delay_entre_comandos") set_option(&delay_entre_comandos,xml_type,xml_value);
    if(string_cache=="generate_report") set_option(&should_report,xml_type,xml_value);

  }
}
int main()
{


return 0;
}
```

the code is not compilling, i not guessing why, is any way to indicate the compiller that every branch of the code is a diferent situation, and it cannot try to deduce the type for all the cases?
Thx in advance

Also, i was trying to indicate the type to the compiller for example:

```
if(type=="float") convertoToNumber<float>(aValuePtr,aValue);
```

it action generate more compile errors.
Compiler Out:

```
cannot convert 'int*' to 'bool*' for argument '1' to 'void {anonymous}::alpha_to_bool(bool*, const string&)'
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'bool' to 'bool&'
```

Indicating that the line:

```
 if(type=="bool") alpha_to_bool(aValuePtr,aValue);
```

Have error

Comment: Seems rather self explanatory, aValuePtr is of type int* and the function expects bool*. Probably because of this line: if(string_cache=="generate_report") set_option(&should_report,xml_type,xml_value); It seems should_report is an int.

Comment: This is not a good design for XML parsing. You are trying to parse the XML type at run-time, but assign it to a value whose type is set at compile-time. That can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All functions in this program are template functions, except `alpha_to_bool`. This means that when `alpha_to_bool` is called from the implicit specialisation `set_option<int>` it is being called with an int* as its argument, but it of course demands a bool*

Answer (score 1):

No matter what `T` is, when your compiler compiles `set_option<T>`, it has to compile the expression `alpha_to_bool(aValuePtr, aValue)`.

Naturally, this works badly when `T` is anything other than `bool`, and thus half of your calls to `set_option` can't possibly work, because they pass in pointers to types other than `bool`.

You should *overload* set_option or some other similar approach: e.g.

```
void set_option(bool * aValuePtr,const char * xml_type,const char * xml_value )
{
  std::string type(xml_type);
  std::string aValue(xml_value);
  if(type=="bool") {
    alpha_to_bool(aValuePtr,aValue);
  } else {
    throw std::runtime_error("Attempted to assign " + type + " to a `bool'");
  }
}
```

and similarly for the remaining types.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this issue:
this line was the problem:

```
if(type=="bool") alpha_to_bool(aValuePtr,aValue);
```

and i change for this:

```
if(type=="bool") alpha_to_bool(reinterpret_cast<bool *>(aValuePtr),aValue);
```

it compiles and works, but still i dont understand why the compiler was tryng to deduce wrong the type.......